# sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension

Tags: python, sqlite

On python3.7.4 loading sqlite3 modules and requesting to enable_load_extension gives:

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect("./tests/data/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.sqlite")
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
```

`AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension'`

I understand the default Ubuntu `sqlite3` package is building with load_extension deactivated. I have followed this guideline: https://charlesleifer.com/blog/compiling-sqlite-for-use-with-python-applications/

Basically, compiled sqlite3 with flag: `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION`, using `pyenv` and building `python 3.7.4` on verbose mode I can see the load extension flag being used,  also following hte above tutorial and reinstalling pysqlite3 on pyenv

Running python on verbose mode:

```
>>> import sqlite3
# /home/jesus/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/jesus/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py
```

The path to the module is correct.

Using the sqlite3 client:

```
jesus@earth:~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.31.0 2019-11-16 12:04:38
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> SELECT sqlite_compileoption_used('ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION');
1
```

I see that sqlite was build with the proper options

Never the the less I continue to have the same error of: `AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension'`

**Update**
Requesting by SQL, if the library was compiled with load extension loading the reply is positive

```
cursor=conn.cursor() 
res=cursor.execute("SELECT sqlite_compileoption_used('ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION');") 
res.fetchall() [(1,)]
```

I am lost on what more can I do to debug the problem. This is happening on pyenv build

Any tips??

Comment: Pick one from [`[python] sqlite3 version`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+sqlite3+version)

Comment: Are you sure that Python and sqlite3 use the same library? Maybe try the "SELECT sqlite_compileoption_used..." from a Python script.

Comment: ```
cursor=conn.cursor()
res=cursor.execute("SELECT sqlite_compileoption_used('ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION');")
res.fetchall()
[(1,)]

```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The python has to be installed with augmented system variables for SQLite and python options. This works for me:

```bash
# Do the following in your shell
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include" PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions" pyenv install 3.7.6
```

Comment: This worked for me! Just replaced `pyenv` with `asdf python`.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who uses macOS, brew and pyenv:

```
brew install sqlite
```

```
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix sqlite)/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix sqlite)/include" PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions" pyenv install -v 3.11.4
```